# Convert HEX string into base64 in Python

Tags: python, base64, hex

is it even possible to have an input converted ?

> from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

> d = input('What"s your HEX string?  ')
>
> b64 = b64encode(bytes.fromhex(d)).decode()
>
> print("Your HEX in base64 is:",  b64)

```
**b64 = b64encode(bytes.fromhex(d)).decode()
```

ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1**

Comment: What input are you providing?

Answer (score 0):

After spending a few hours I finally figured it out. Had to alter the b64 var and take out .decode()

```
d = input("Enter HEX here: ")

b64 = b64encode(bytes.fromhex(d))

print("Your HEX in base64 is:", b64)
```

Answer (score 0):

encodings can be found in `codecs` module.
Try using this

```
import codecs
b64 = codecs.encode(codecs.decode(d, 'hex'), 'base64').decode()
```